# How range queries identified attribute name in analytic function oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Prototype of range windows is defined as below

```
Function( ) OVER (PARTITION BY <expr1> ORDER BY <expr2> RANGE BETWEEN
<start_expr> AND <end_expr>)
or
Function( ) OVER (PARTITION BY <expr1> ORDER BY <expr2> RANGE [<start_expr>
PRECEDING or UNBOUNDED PRECEDING]
```

It's not mentioned that range is given for which attributes(X) then how parser/evaluation engine identifies attributes(X) .

```
SELECT deptno, empno, sal,
Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal RANGE
BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND (sal/2) PRECEDING) CNT_LT_HALF,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal RANGE
BETWEEN (sal/2) FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) CNT_MT_HALF
FROM emp
ORDER BY deptno, sal;
```

In above SQL query range is applied on employee salary .How parser/evaluation engine identifies that the range is given for sal. Since no where it is mentioned that sal is between some value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PARTITION BY deptno` defines groups

`ORDER BY sal` defines the order of rows in each group

`RANGE BETWEEN [start] AND [end]` defines **a window for each row** in each group. You cannot specify this clause unless you have specified the ORDER BY. Some window boundaries defined by the RANGE clause let you specify only one expression in the ORDER BY.

`RANGE` specifies the window as a logical offset. It looks only at ORDER BY expression(s) to determine a window.

In your example `RANGE` is set for each row. For each row it determines the rows which are used by the analytic function. These rows are FROM the begining of the group TO the max row having salary <= the salary of the current row (as you can see it would be impossible to determine without ORDER BY, that's why windowing clause requires ordering).

```
id  depno  sal
1   1       5
2   1       6
3   1       10   
4   2       1   
5   2       2   
6   2       5   
7   2       6
```

For the row with id = 6 the window will be

```
id  depno  sal
4   2       1   -- UNBOUNDED PRECEDING (start with the first row in the group: depno = 2)
5   2       2   -- this row has the salary < the salary of the row with id=6 (2 < 5/2)
```

Comment: That means range is define on expression expr if ORDER BY is defined as **ORDER BY expr** .  But what happened if expression contains more than one attributes .

Comment: @sonu kumar There are two windowing keywords: ROWS and RANGE. For ROWS you can have any number of expressions. For RANGE there are some special restrictions.

Comment: @sonu kumar If you have several expressions in ORDER BY you cannot use RANGE with X PRECEDING or X FOLLOWING. But you can for example use RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING

Comment: Yup , Row can be used since it's worked on the row number . So it can be applied on any expression .